# Django - How to improve performance when model contains a large JSONField?

Tags: django, performance, django-models, orm, django-orm

I am working on trying to figure out how to enhance performance when filtering on a queryset that has a JSONField with large data (thousands of lines).

Even when querying and returning an estimated 100 objects, the return is extremely slow. 10-20 seconds.

I have come to realize that the issue is the JSONfield, and the fact that large datasets are being stored in this field.

I was reading about Djangos `.only()` and `.defer()` methods, because I don't need any data in this JSONField, but the performance seems to be the exact same without using these methods.

I am just looking for some guidance on how to improve some performance here.

Comment: Are you free to change your Model?  If so I would redesign, to put the large data  into a completely different model linked with a ForeignKey, so it is only fetched when you need it. Split it up if you need to filter on some of the smaller parts of the JSONField.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a for loop after the query (in your template or in your view) there could be implied additional queries you are executing.

Using [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) in the query before the loop could prevent further additional queries, and improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

Have tried to use .values() or values_list()?